# yarn / npm bulld completes then hangs indefinitely

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

Anyone have any experience with this? Running `yarn build` completes the build but never exits the process, it just hangs... The same thing happens when i run `npm run build`

```
stars-app|master⚡ ⇒ yarn build
yarn build v0.27.5
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  132.04 KB  build/static/js/main.54f97667.js
  24.93 KB   build/static/css/main.43aab3e7.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build
```

Totally fine build, no errors. Yet the process never completes and just hangs... Ideas? There's nothing special about my package.json either. Also, building any other project completes fine so I know it's not my global yarn / npm packages... it is something with this particular project... Suggestions on how to even begin to troubleshoot this sort of thing?

Comment: Can y ou please add your webpack config?